# What is the field order in "query" field of currentOp based on?

Tags: mongodb

This has been driving me nuts and might just be a silly question. I am trying to improve perf on a huge mongo database. We use python to interact with the db. The table is set with compound index and the order of the index reflects the order in which I am reading and writing to the table.

DB schema looks like:

```
    {
    key: { a: "", b: "", c: "", d: "", e: "", f: "" }
    value: { ... }
    }
```

Compound index is on

```
key.a: -1, key.b: 1, key.c: 1, key.d: 1
```

The upserts using python respect this order. Even the reads do.
But when I do db.currentOp(), the order is not how the query was written.

```
      {
        "opid" : ,
        "active" : true,
        "ns" : "",
        "query" : {
            "key.f" : "",
            "key.e" : "",
            "key.c" : "",
            "key.b" : "",
            "key.d" : "",
            "key.a" : ISODate("2014-09-18T18:00:00Z")
        },
       }
```

My question is does the "query" field show the order in which mongo is querying? Or is it just a display thing?

Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Yes the order in "query" is how mongo gets the query and how it is executed. The problem here is the dictionary used to read & upsert are not ordered (python).

Looks like mongo api already has answer to that problem - 
http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/bson/son.html